# A question about normal sets in a finite subgroup

Tags: finite-groups

Let $G$ a finite non-abelian group and suppose that $N$ is a normal *subset* (not a subgroup) of $G$, that is, $aN=Na$ for every $a\in G$. Under what conditions $|N|$ divides $|G|$ ?

Comment: Is there any particular context you care about?  If, say, $G$ is abelian then every subset is normal...

Comment: I mean especially when $G$ is non-abelian (i edited my question)

Comment: @ThePortakal Yes, that's Lagrange's Theorem. Yet here it is given *a subset*, **not** a subgroup. Perhaps a typo, perhaps that's what the OP really means.

Comment: I mean a subset - not a subgroup.

Comment: Though, again, if $G$ has a non-trivial center then any subset of that will work...so perhaps you meant to also assume that $Z(G)=e$ or something close to that?

Comment: This sounds interesting @lulu... can you please elaborate?

Comment: It will be the case if $N$ is a class of conjugacy of $G$.

Comment: Well, If we take $N\subset Z(G)$ then of course $N$ commutes with every group element, so it is trivially normal.  Now, if $|Z(G)|≤2$ this doesn't tell us much (since the subsets $N$ would have either one or two elements and we don't learn anything about $|G|$ either way).  But if $|Z(G)|>2$ there are interesting subsets.

Comment: But this is perhaps a condition of such N to exist, why $|N|$ divides $|G|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$N$ is necessarily the union of entire conjugacy classes. The size of every conjugacy class divides $|G|$ (by the orbit stabiliser theorem) so if $N$ consists of only one conjugacy class, its size will divide the group order. If it contains more than one conjugacy class, not much can be said about divisibility in general. For example, in $S_n$ you could make $N$ the union of any set of classes of all permutations with certain cycle-types. So in $S_4$ the size of $N$ could be any of 1,3,8,6,6 or any of their sums.